# is there an effective (possibly) native way of JQuery and RaphaelJS intertwined?

Tags: jquery, raphael

Where JQuery is (to my understanding) completely DOM based, and Raphael is just the opposite, how can I use the best of both worlds in the same document? is there any efficient way to achieve that?

further notes:
I know that Raphael would create actual DOM elements in the code but their IDs require me to go into every element I create and then try to incorporate it into the JQuery. is there any easy way to use Raphael on DOM elements rather then on scripted elements?

Thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunatly Raphael can not work with DOM elements which it did not create. What you can do however, is to import svg using [raphael-svg-import](https://github.com/wout/raphael-svg-import) library, so in conjunction with jQuery it will look like this:

```
var mySvg = $('svg#IdOfMySVGElement')
var paper = Raphael(10, 10, 800, 500);
var set = paper.set();
paper.importSVG(mySvg.html(), set);
//the whole svg will be recreated so we need to remove the original
mySvg.remove();
```

Bear in mind that it will work with svg enabled browsers only. For VML you will need to look for another solution or write your own vml parser.